# Etymology of legend (as used in a chart/map)?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology

Related question: [“Legend” or “key”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11878/legend-or-key)

*Legend*, also known as [a Chart's Key](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/l/g/2012-07-04-excel-chart-legend.htm), often located on the right hand side of the chart or graph.

It took me some time to understand what the legend was when learning programming with charting controls. Now I am wondering how this usage originated.

Legend, as used in the film *I am Legend* is *a narrative of human actions* How was this word chosen to be used as *key in chart*?

To a non-technical English speaker, is there difficulty in learning "legend of the chart/legend of the graph", or is this usage intuitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**legend**

- Early 14th century: *"narrative dealing with a happening or an event,"* from Old French **legende** (12th century, Modern French **légende**) and directly from Medieval Latin **legenda** *"legend, story,"* literally *"(things) to be read,"* on certain days in church, etc., from Latin **legendus**, neuter plural gerundive of **legere** *"to read, gather, select"*
- Used originally of saints' lives; extended sense of *"nonhistorical or mythical story"* first recorded late 14th century. Meaning *"writing or inscription"* (especially on a coin or medal) is from 1610s; on a map, illustration, etc., from 1903.

Looks to me like it hasn't been used with regards to maps until the early twentieth century.

Comment: Good to learn. Reference link, please? maybe online dictionary?

Comment: My apologies: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=legend

Comment: It could be considered a guide on "how to read" the chart/map, which would connect to the Latin root.