# What do you call the symbols list on a map?

Tags: single-word-requests

Every map has symbols that describe things.
In the corner of a map, there is a list that explains what each symbol means.

What is the name of that list? (What title should I put above this list)?

Comment: Did you look at other maps to see what label they give?

Comment: The answer to this question distinguishes between a legend and a key: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11878/legend-or-key/11881#11881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A legend is the **area of a map** where the symbols used on that map are explained. The complete symbol sets that are used systematically throughout many maps or map sets are called **symbologies**.

See preface to US Chart 1 here. I am unable to convert pdf snippet at the moment.

http://www.nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/mcd/chart1/ChartNo1.pdf

**symbology**

> 3 :  a system of symbols

M-W symbology: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/symbology

Comment: The list of symbols etc can also be called the 'key', for most of my life I thought that 'key' was the only name for it. 'Legend' seems to be more recent in the UK, is it originally American.

Answer (score 3):

The list is called legend.Please look up the word in Merriam-Webster online dictionary "a list that explains the symbols on a map".

Comment: Please quote your corroboration. Please don't expect people to go and look it up for themselves: your answer should be complete in itself.

Answer (score 2):

The table is called a 'legend' . Moreover it features a special diagram adjacent to it, with a rectangle containing an upright black filled triangle.